# What is a difference between the encoding nominal variable and ordering variable?

Tags: r, variables, machine-learning, encoding

Shouldn't I approach nominal categorical variables and ordinal variables differently? It seems to me that a simple change from text values to numbers may then suggest a certain relationship between nominal variables.

How do you do it during your data pre-processing in R?

Comment: I don’t really understand what your question is. Yes, (of course) there’s a difference, and they should be treated differently. But you seem to know this. Then what?

Comment: What specific methods do you recommend for these two types of variables?

Answer (score 1):

R has slightly distinct data types for categorical (nominal) variables and ordinal variables.

Specifically, categorical data is typically encoded as [`factor`s](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html). Ordinal variables are a special case of categorical variables, and thus are *also* factors — but *ordered* factors.

In terms of R code, the difference is thus simply setting a parameter in the `factor` function call:

```
paygrades = c('intern', 'junior', 'senior', 'manager')

employees = data.frame(
    Name = c('Alice', 'Bob', 'Cecil', 'Dan', 'Emily', 'Felix'),
    Role = factor(c('engineer', 'accounting', 'marketing', 'CEO', 'testing', 'engineer')),
    Paygrade = factor(c('senior', 'junior', 'intern', 'manager', 'senior', 'junior'), levels = paygrades, ordered = TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

If we now inspect the data, we find:

```
employees$Role
# [1] engineer   accounting marketing  CEO        testing    engineer
# Levels: accounting CEO engineer marketing testing
employees$Paygrade
# [1] senior  junior  intern  manager senior  junior
# Levels: intern < junior < senior < manager
```